# How do i change Active Directory Password in Windows 2012 Terminal Server without Using CTRL ALT

Tags: windows-server-2012, rdp, terminal-server, password-management

How do I change Active Directory Password in Windows 2012 Terminal Server without Using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>

I can't use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>END</kbd> And <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd>
Is there any other method for invoking the Security Screen ?

Comment: This is actually a good question - on previous versions of Windows you had a "Windows Security" option in the Start Menu which was great in locked down environments.

Comment: Good question as @dan says but I think the answer might not be good: I've tried a 'normal' server and one with the desktop experience installed and there's nothing I can see.

Comment: All of you people are simply amazing. I had to ask our service desk to reset my password since I didn't know any of these other methods.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is the best I've got so far - log on to an older (I'm using Server 2008 R2) server with the `Windows Security` shortcut displayed in the start menu. Open the Start Menu and drag the `Windows Security` item to the desktop.

The resulting shortcut can be used on a 2012 box.

The CLSID it calls is `{2559a1f2-21d7-11d4-bdaf-00c04f60b9f0}`, and you can use to launch the Windows Security screen to change the password interactively:

```
explorer shell:::{2559a1f2-21d7-11d4-bdaf-00c04f60b9f0}
```

This should work from the Run dialog or a Command Prompt.

Comment: Better than a poke in the eye, but *thank you Microsoft* again.

Comment: it does not work with windows 8+

Answer (score 5):

We found out creating a vbs script with

```
    Dim objShell
    Set objShell = CreateObject("shell.application")
    objshell.WindowsSecurity
    Set objShell = nothing
```

works

Comment: Another try could be invoking `net user <username> /domain` from an elevated command prompt.

Answer (score 5):

Based on the above answers, you can create a shortcut to the following location (right click on Desktop>New>Shortcut)

`explorer shell:::{2559a1f2-21d7-11d4-bdaf-00c04f60b9f0}`

It should also work if launched from command line (if you want to script it). Add a nice icon from %SYSTEMROOT%\System32\imageres.dll, and you're good to go. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 4):

I always change it via On-Screen Keyboard.

Type OSK and launch the virtual keyboard.

Press `CTRL + ALT` and click on `END` with the mouse.

This will invoke a security screen, where you can change the password.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Using the OSK is the easiest option of these answers. I had to do CTRL+ALT+DEL instead of CTRL+ALT+END when RDP into a 2012 R2 though.