# Windows Security Options over RDP in Server 2012+

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2, rdp

In Server 2008 R2 and below, there was a "Windows Security" option in the Start Menu to access the "Ctrl+Alt"Delete" options without pressing Ctrl+Alt+End. I always found that useful since I often RDP to Windows Servers from my Mac (since I don't have an "End" key on it). Now, with Server 2012 (and R2), I've looked and looked for this the equivalent and cannot find it. Is it still possible to launch the Windows Security Options screen from the Start Screen or a desktop shortcut?

EDIT: Never mind, I found the solution. See my comment.

Comment: Never mind, I found a solution. This question solved it http://serverfault.com/questions/546644/how-do-i-change-active-directory-password-in-windows-2012-terminal-server-withou?rq=1

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand your question. Glad you found an answer though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do i change Active Directory Password in Windows 2012 Terminal Server without Using CTRL ALT](https://serverfault.com/questions/546644/how-do-i-change-active-directory-password-in-windows-2012-terminal-server-withou)

Comment: I found the answer [in this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/546644/how-do-i-change-active-directory-password-in-windows-2012-terminal-server-withou)

Comment: Since you found your own solution, you should add it an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for it too in order to change Windows Password.

Found an old VB to force the screen to show. See below:

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

objShell.WindowsSecurity
```

Save as .vbs and you are all set.

Comment: It does not work.